# Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally (there is no split views in my app)

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So this app was released to the app store about a month ago. I haven't done anything with it for awhile but today I went to go in and start working on an update. I get this error when trying to prevent a view controller modally. The view controller is the same, standard viewcontroller and there are no split views anywhere in the app.

Does anyone know what could make it think the view is split view? I've never even made a split view controller before.

```
AddEntryViewController_iPad *vc = [[AddEntryViewController_iPad alloc]init];


vc.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

update: this only occurs on the simulator. When I run it on the device it works fine...dont get it.

Comment: Is this an iphone app (as the tag suggests) or an ipad app (as the splitView suggests)?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: iPad. Ther error is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally...

Comment: Unless there is some other presentModalViewController happening somewhere else that is causing this error, it really does seem like AddEntryViewController_iPad must be a subclass of UISplitViewController. Otherwise I suppose it's possible that the text of the error message is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i fixed it just by changing it to the following:

```
AddEntryViewController_iPad *vc = [[AddEntryViewController_iPad alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil ];
```

Strange because it works fine the other way from other viewControllers.